# C - local pointer to int lost half size

Tags: c

In a local function I wanted to count how many nodes points to each other (in-degree) in a graph, and it is represented by adjacent lists. The odd thing is, when I print in this function, I have all the numbers correctly, but I lost half of them when passing out of the function.

```
VertexType *InDegree( Graph G )
{
    int Size, i;
    Size = G->GraphSize; // Size is 17

    VertexType *degree;

    for (i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        degree[ i ] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
    {
        VertexNodePtr P;
        P = G->Vertices[ i ].AdjList;

        // A traverse, not relevant to this question
        while (P != NULL)
        {
            ++degree[ P->Vertex ];
            P = P->Next;
        }
    }
    // here I can print all the numbers using a
    // for-loop counting to 17, correctly.
    // but sizeof() gives me half the length I expect!
    // which is 8. And out of this function counting to
    // 17 causes an overflow.
    return degree;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` is an operator which is unable to determine the size of a dynamically allocated array (or static array decayed to pointer). The result is 8 because you are probably calculating it on a pointer type (eg `VertexType*`) and it returns the size in bytes of a pointer, which is 8 bytes on a 64 byte architecture.

Ignore `sizeof` result in this specific circumstance, when dealing with arrays, it is able just do calculate total amount of bytes for a static (or local array).

Comment: Thanks, I checked it ignoring `sizeof`, it is correct. Overflow must be a bug somewhere else.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a macro.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(degree)` is the size of a *pointer* not the number of nodes, or even teh size of a single node.

At the line:

```
degree[ i ] = 0;
```

You are dereferencing an unitialised pointer, and then writing a value to it! `degree` has to point to something valid before you do that.  The code is likely to crash and is certainly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sizeof(x)` gets the size of the pointer itself (which is `8` in your case because you are compiling a 64-bit program), and *NOT* the object it points to.

That means that `sizeof(T*)` is the same (either `4` or `8` on x86/amd64), regardless of `T`.

Unfortunately, there is no function to get the length of the object *pointed to*, so you're going to keep track of that yourself.

One thing to note is that `sizeof(x)` gets the *actual size* (in bytes, not # of members) for arrays (not to be mixed with pointers *to* arrays):

```
int a[10] = 5;
int* ap = a;

// outputs `10 * sizeof(int)` --- `4` for most modern architectures
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
// outputs the size of the *pointer* (usually 4 or 8)
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ap));
```

---

It should be noted that in parameters, an `int a[10]` declaration is just a pointer:

```
void printA(int a[10]) {
    // outputs *SIZE OF POINTER* --- 4 or 8
    //     --- because `a` is actually just a pointer!
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
}
```

... thus, the following are completely equivalent(*NOTE below):

```
void printA(int a[10]) {...}
void printA(int a[]) {...}
void printA(int* a) {...}
```

*NOTE: There might be a slight difference, in that a compiler could emit a warning when the sizes don't match for the `int a[10]` variant; but this is merely a vendor extension, and as far as the standard is concerned, they're all the same.*